# Threading program in python running successfully on IDLE but not on shell, command line

Tags: python, multithreading

I am using python 3.8 on windows 10. I am able to run threading programs succesfully on IDLE but, the same programs do not start on command line or when I double click them. The shell pops up and exits quickly even when threads are not started. I even tried to catch any runtime errors and any errors using except but I got neither on IDLE and the program was still terminating abruptly on shell.

Here is an example -

```
    import threading
    import time
    try:
        def func():
            for i in range(10):
                print(i)
                time.sleep(0.1)                 

        t1 = threading.Thread(target = func)

        t1.start()
        #t1.join() # i tried this also
        while t1.is_alive():
            time.sleep(0.1) #trying to return back, i added this when the threads were not working

        input() #waiting for the user to press any key before exit
    except RuntimeError:
        print('runtime error')
        input()
    except: # any error
        print('Some error')
        input()
```

Comment: I can't understand why people are downvoting me? Please give the reason here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I had made a file by the name 'threading.py' in the directory. This file was causing Attribute Error of python because it has the same name as the 'threading' module of python. I renamed it and my programs are working jolly good!